# Android ActionBar: Set text color of action view?

Tags: android, styles, android-actionbar

I've found how to change a lot of the other style information in the Android 3.0 ActionBar, but I haven't been able to figure out what style definitions to use to change the text color on a item created with the "withText" attribute.

Is there a way to do this app-wide in a custom theme?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the theme attribute `android:actionMenuTextColor`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know how I missed this.

Comment: may be you know how to change the color of menu item text? Can't find it

Comment: Thanks! But is there a way to set the disabled text color to be different?

Comment: You can use a color state list with a disabled state defined.

Comment: To create custom actionViews that match those colors, you can apply the style TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu